# Why does this simple COUNT query not work with this alias? "Column not found"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This may be two issues.  Using mysql/mariadb.
I'm trying to find duplicates of a certain field.

```
SELECT field1, COUNT(*) c FROM table1 WHERE c > 1 GROUP BY field1;

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'
```

If I put the alias in quotes, it works but does not find the duplicates:

```
SELECT field1, COUNT(*) 'c' FROM table1 WHERE 'c' > 1 GROUP BY field1;
```

And for clarification, it does find duplicates ( >1 ) if I don't use the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `having` clause, not a `where` clause:

```
SELECT field1, COUNT(*) as c
FROM table1
GROUP BY field1
HAVING c > 1 ;
```

`HAVING` filters *after* aggregation.  `WHERE` filters before.  All other things aside, the value of `c` is not known before aggregation.  (Other things being that column aliases are simply not allowed in `WHERE` clauses.)

Answer (score 0):

As a compliment to Gordon's answer, a `WHERE` clause *would* be appropriate if you first computed the counts in a separate subquery:

```
SELECT field1, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT field1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY field1
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Or, you could just move your `WHERE` logic to a `HAVING` clause and avoid the subquery.